# Display block with one main post with intro and several with links only

Tags: php

I display boxes with news. Every box is from a different category.

Here is the screenshot of what I try to accomplish:

[Display boxes with news from every category](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21995476/display-boxes-with-news-from-every-category)

But check only the design, leave the PHP code. It is outdated question. (Sorry for putting this link, but I cannot attach images. Low scores)

After the main post I try to show the rest of the news, but i can only display the main post and after that the list with posts in which the first post is duplicated.

Here is my code:

```
public function category_box($category_id, $category_name) {
        $this->_db->query("SELECT * from posts WHERE category_id = '$category_id'");
        $this->current_category_posts = $this->_db->resultset();

        $posts = array();

        foreach ($this->current_category_posts as $post) {
            if ($post['category_id'] === $category_id) {
                $posts[] = $post;
            }
        }

        include VIEWS_PATH . 'homepage/category_box.php';
    }
```

And this is one view file for the category box:

```
<div class="category-box">
    <div class="category-name">
        <?php print $category_name ?>
    </div><!-- end div.category-name -->

    <div class="category-box-content">
        <h2><a href="#"><?php print $post['post_title']; ?></a></h2>
        <div class="published-date">
            <?php print $post['post_published_date']; ?>
        </div><!-- end div.published-date -->
        <div class="main-photo">
            <a href="#"><img src="<?php print BASE_URL . 'public/uploads/images/' . $post['post_photo']; ?>" alt=""></a>
            <span class="photo-caption">
                <?php print $post['post_photo_caption']; ?>
            </span><!-- end div.photo-caption -->
        </div><!-- end div.main-photo -->
        <div class="excerpt">
            <a href="#" 
               title="<?php print $post['post_content']; ?>"><?php print $post['post_content']; ?></a>
        </div><!-- end div.excerpt -->
        <div class="latest-posts">
            <div class="more-publications">
                More publications in <?php print $category_name ?>
            </div>
            <ul>
                <?php
                foreach ($this->current_category_posts as $post_in_list) {
                    if ($post_in_list['category_id'] === $category_id) {
                        print '<li><a href="#" title="' . $post_in_list['post_title'] . '" >' .
                                $post_in_list['post_title'];
                        '</a></li>';
                    }
                }
                ?>
            </ul>
            <a href="#" class="all-publications">All publications &raquo;</a>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div><!-- end div.latest-posts -->
    </div><!-- end div.category-box-content -->
</div><!-- end div.category-box -->
```

This is how I display each box (maybe not important for the question):

```
                $post->category_box("1", "World");
                $post->category_box("2", "Politics");
                $post->category_box("3", "Culture");
                $post->category_box("4", "Technologies");
                $post->category_box("5", "Sports");
                $post->category_box("6", "Art");
```

How can I accomplish this?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Hard to tell what your actual question is here (and how it differs from the first one). Is getting the remaining posts after the first one to be displayed as “links only”, so not the _full_ post view, the main problem? Well then you could simply add a third parameter to the method `category_box`, name it `$show_full_view` or something – and then pass `true` for the first call, and `false` for all the following. And _in_ that method, you decide what to display based on that value.

Comment: Hmm! Interesting. Sounds hard but I will try it! Thank you for the idea. :)

Comment: Oh.. the parameters are in the entire box with the posts... Hm..

Answer (score 0):

Well, if I'm right you want to exclude the main post from the category boxes even though the category applies to the main post. Now in the part of your view where you do this:

```
<ul>
   <?php
     foreach ($this->current_category_posts as $post_in_list) {
        if ($post_in_list['category_id'] === $category_id) {
           print '<li><a href="#" title="' . $post_in_list['post_title'] . '" >' 
                   . $post_in_list['post_title'] .
                  '</a></li>';
        }
     }
   ?>
</ul>
```

If you compare the main post id to the category posts id like this:

```
<ul>
   <?php
     foreach ($this->current_category_posts as $post_in_list) {
        if ($post_in_list['category_id'] === $category_id && $post_in_list['id'] !== $main_post_id) {
           print '<li><a href="#" title="' . $post_in_list['post_title'] . '" >' 
                   . $post_in_list['post_title'] .
                  '</a></li>';
        }
     }
   ?>
</ul>
```

you're already there. However it is recommended you keep your PHP logic outside of the view. , if you're aiming for readable and maintainable code.

Comment: Hey! Thanx! But what is $main_post_id and where it comes from? I dont have it and I do not see how I could use. All my posts are the same.

Comment: Hi. You would have to pass it yourself to the view in the controller. You can also do the check for the main post id in the category box function. But you will also have to pass it yourself to the function. Quite frankly without your entire code I can't tell you where you should get it from.